# Connect Server C Drive with out using RDC

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, remote-desktop, remote-access

We have some issue in connecting the server via Remote Desktop Connection. It is not at all connecting

As the server got low memory space in c drive we are unable to connect.

I would like to know is there any way, we connect the Server using IP address and goto C drive and delete unwanted files?

I have only IP address and do not aware of where the server is located physically.
Any command prompt utility can help us for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the administrative share to access the C drive directly ( \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\c$ ) but if your problem is low memory, deleting file will not help: you'll need to reboot or terminate some processes in order to free up memory.

Comment: If you reboot, make sure you have enough space free on the C: drive or it might not boot correctly.